# how to get type safety for html data-* attributes

Tags: typescript

How to get typesafety for html data-* attributes

```
    interface DivProps {
        id?:string 
        class?:string
        // allow data-*  ? 
    }

    function div(props:DivProps) {

    }
const d = div({"data-id":"1"})
```

Comment: No way currently. Related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579#issuecomment-552653987